# Premature end of script headers: php-cgi and internal server error

Tags: php, excel, content-management-system

need some helps here: i try to import some excel sheets to my website, but the page keep loading and then stop working and showing internal server error text. the error log shows this caused by the import.php :Premature end of script headers: php-cgi, referer: ...file_import.php.

below are the codes:

```
<? include("../include/begin.inc.php");?>
<?

function showerror()
{
  die("Error " . mysql_errno() . " : " . mysql_error());
}

function sava_data($array, $table){
$count = 0; 
$total = 0; 
foreach( $array as $tmp){
  if ($count <> 0){ 
    $date =  date("Y:m:d H:i:s"); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table set ";

    $sql .= "detail = '{$tmp[2]}', shape = '{$tmp[3]}', qty = '{$tmp[4]}', price = '{$tmp[5]}', percent = '{$tmp[6]}', colour = '{$tmp[7]}', clarity = '{$tmp[8]}', prop = '{$tmp[9]}', polish = '{$tmp[10]}', smy = '{$tmp[11]}', diam = '{$tmp[12]}', t_dep = '{$tmp[13]}', `table` = '{$tmp[14]}', fl = '{$tmp[15]}', colour_shade = '{$tmp[16]}', cert = '{$tmp[17]}', cert_no = '{$tmp[18]}', per_kg = '{$tmp[19]}', selling_price = '{$tmp[20]}', status = 'new', create_date = '{$date}'";
    //echo $sql."<br>";
    //exit();
    if (!($result = @mysql_query($sql) or die("Error:" . mysql_error().$sql)))
      showerror();

    $total++;
   }
   $count++; 


}
return $total;  
}

function save_data2($array,$table){
$count = 0; 
$total = 0; 
foreach( $array as $tmp){
  if ($count <> 0){ 
    $date =  date("Y:m:d H:i:s"); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table set ";

    $sql .= "detail = '{$tmp[2]}', shape = '{$tmp[3]}', qty = '{$tmp[4]}', price = '{$tmp[5]}', percent = '{$tmp[6]}', colour = '{$tmp[7]}', clarity = '{$tmp[8]}', prop = '{$tmp[9]}', polish = '{$tmp[10]}', smy = '{$tmp[11]}', diam = '{$tmp[12]}', t_dep = '{$tmp[13]}', `table` = '{$tmp[14]}', fl = '{$tmp[15]}', colour_shade = '{$tmp[16]}', cert = '{$tmp[17]}', cert_no = '{$tmp[18]}', per_kg = '{$tmp[19]}', selling_price = '{$tmp[20]}', status = 'new', create_date = '{$date}'";
    //echo $sql."<br>";
    //exit();
    if (!($result = @mysql_query($sql) or die("Error:" . mysql_error().$sql)))
      showerror();

    $total++;
   }
   $count++;
}
return $total;
}

function empty_data($table){
    if($table == "fancy_table"){
        $s3 = "select * from $table where file != ''";
        $r3 = mysql_query($s3);
        while($d3 = mysql_fetch_array($r3)){
            $del_lo_l="../../_files/fancy_product/".$d3['file'];
            if(file_exists($del_lo_l))
            {
                @unlink($del_lo_l);
            }
        }

    }
$s4 = "truncate table `$table`";
mysql_query($s4);
$s5 = "OPTIMIZE TABLE `$table`";
mysql_query($s5);
}

//error_reporting(E_ALL ^​​ E_NOTICE);
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if($_POST){
if($action == "empty"){
  empty_data("artwork");
}else if($action == "imported"){ 
  $Import_TmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

  $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(); 
  $data->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8');
  $data->read($Import_TmpFile);

  $total = 0;
  //for ($i = 4; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
        for ($i = 4; $i <= 65536; $i++) {
    if ($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2] <> ""){ 
      $sql = "INSERT INTO artwork set detail = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2]."', shape = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3]."', qty = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4]."', price = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5]."', percent = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][6]."', colour = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][7]."', clarity = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][8]."', prop = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][9]."', polish = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][10]."', smy = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][11]."', diam = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][12]."', t_dep = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][13]."', `table` = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][14]."', fl = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][15]."', colour_shade = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][16]."', cert = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][17]."', cert_no = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][18]."', per_kg = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][19]."', selling_price = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][20]."', status = 'new', create_date = now()";
      $result = @mysql_query($sql);
      $total++;
    }
  }
  echo $total;
  //$total = sava_data($array, "artwork");
}else if($action == "fancy_imported"){ 
  $Import_TmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader(); 
  $data->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8');
  $data->read($Import_TmpFile);
  $total = 0;
  //for ($i = 4; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {
        for ($i = 4; $i <= 65536; $i++) {
    if ($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2] <> ""){ 
      $sql = "INSERT INTO fancy_style set detail = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2]."', artworktype = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3]."', shape = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4]."', qty = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5]."', colour = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][6]."', cut = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][7]."', measurements = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][8]."', treatment = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][9]."', origin = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][10]."', comments = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][11]."', cert = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][12]."', cert_no = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][13]."', `per_kg` = '".$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][14]."', status = 'new', create_date = now()";
      $result = @mysql_query($sql);
      $total++;
    }
  }
  echo $total;

}else if($action == "fancy_empty"){
  empty_data("fancy_style");
}
}  
//exit();
jsRedirect(geturlname().".php?action=".$action."&rows=".$total);

?>
<? include("../include/end.inc.php");?>
```

Comment: Do you have permissions set properly on the files you're trying to access?

Comment: hello camel, i check all folder permissions are 755, all files permission are 644. how to know which files the script try to access? the web developer did not tell me about this . thanks!

Comment: This might be part of the reason. You should try adjusting the files to 705 (or 755) and see if this will remove the error. Start with the files closest to the file containing the issue.